# Error inflating class TextView caused by java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, exception, layout, layout-inflater

In my app The user uploads an image to my server, I am having this error on many devices when running a test on FIREBASE TESTLAB

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class TextView
```

Here is the error log

I know the error is caused due to ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
But I do not know how to solve this
I am new to android and am struggling with this

The Array it is calling  are pulled from the server using JSON and I am using Volley to pull the data from the server

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class TextView
     FATAL EXCEPTION: ControllerMessenger
Process: com.smartpractice.dukatholesmartapp, PID: 6863
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class TextView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class TextView
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=16; index=19
    at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:65)
    at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:458)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:1212)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:202)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getString(TintTypedArray.java:143)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:274)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:177)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:93)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:83)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:177)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:102)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:264)
    at es.dmoral.toasty.Toasty.custom(Toasty.java:300)
    at es.dmoral.toasty.Toasty.info(Toasty.java:174)
    at es.dmoral.toasty.Toasty.info(Toasty.java:162)
    at com.smartpractice.myapplication.SecondActivity$5.onResponse(SecondActivity.java:227)
    at com.smartpractice.myapplication.SecondActivity$5.onResponse(SecondActivity.java:224)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.a(Interrogator.java:19)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:166)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:158)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:34)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:77)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:52)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.c(Tap.java:8)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.b(Tap.java:18)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.a(Tap.java:3)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:20)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:9)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:79)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:96)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:3)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Do you have a fontFamily attribute defined in your app theme?

Comment: Yes I have a font family declared but in the XML for the textviews etc.<TextView
           
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito"
      
            />     I removed the ID and layout height etc. to make it easier to read for this comment

Comment: Hi @RubenMeiring did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast Yes, I did it was the font I was using in the app,not correctly assigned to a few textviews etc. I just removes the font and used default